# TypeScript compiler does not transpile modules to javascript

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have imported five libraries in my .ts file as below. When I compile the file using TS 1.8 compiler it only add three imports to .js file resulting undefined VssService and ExtensionDataService. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

**Imports in .ts file**

```
import VssService = require('VSS/Service');
import ExtensionDataService = require('VSS/SDK/Services/ExtensionData');
import tl = require('vsts-task-lib/task');
import url = require('url');
import path = require('path');
```

**Compiled .js**

```
var tl = require('vsts-task-lib/task');
var url = require('url');
var path = require('path');
```

Thanks-

Comment: 404, can you update the link?

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you add VSS.d.ts reference.

Secondly, based on my test, it won’t generate related code if the variable not be used. I added console.log(VssService) and console.log(ExtensionDataService), then these code is generated.